# PLSQL: Declare does not work

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I am using

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

I want to declare a variable in order to use it later on. This is what i did:

```
DECLARE
  price  myBeer VARCHAR(20);;
```

This results in the error:

```
[DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 22:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" while expecting one of the following: := ; not null default character
```

This made me do the following:

```
DECLARE
myBeer VARCHAR(20) :=2;
```

But this also results in an error:

```
[DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 26:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" while expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

Can this really be that hard?

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: `DECLARE price  myBeer VARCHAR(20);;` is not a valid PL/SQL block. Please read the PL/SQL manual

Comment: What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: I want to use the variable later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compile a whole block at once and a variable will only be valid in the scope of an `BEGIN ... END` Block:

```
DECLARE
  myVariableName  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  myVariableName := 'TEST';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Value of var = ' || myVariableName ); -- This works!
END;
/

-- This will not work, since it is outside of the Block!
SELECT myVariableName FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 32:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" while expecting one of the following:

   := ; not null default character
[BEGIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 26:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" while expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL-assignment [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL-assignment
[/ - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  invalid SQL-type

Comment: If you read your first error-message carefully it says "END OF FILE found at ROW2, Column 32" This means you tried to execute just the first two rows and nothing else! If you use SQL-Developer or Toad, maybe you had the first two lines marked and not the whole block? Try execute File instead of execute code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me fine:

```
DECLARE
  price  VARCHAR(20);
begin   
    null;  
end;
```

Seems like your code is not syntactically correct.

EDIT - I posted this code just to make it compile.

Comment: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 20:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" while expecting one of the following:

   := ; not null default character
[BEGIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 8:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" while expecting one of the following:

   ;
 10:33:24  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL-assignement